# What will happen when merging 2 separate git repos into 1 using submodules

Tags: git, github

I have 2 git repos for the same project - 1 is for the backend and 1 for the front-end. Thus I am using 2 private repositories in my git account. Since I have very limited private repos I was wondering if I can reduce the used repos to 1 if I create a super repo and submodule the existing repos. 
Will this set-up need 1 or 3 repos in the end?

Or should I include the repos into the super-repo using mergetree ?

I would like to keep the history of each repo and to reduce the amount of repos I use.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

if you make a super-repo and only include the two sub-module's then you will have three repos, but the super-repo will be tiny.  It mostly holds the SHA~1 of the sub modules and meta information, while the sub-module's hold their own history, independent of the super-module. The super is also a good place to hold any documentation about the subs.  Merging the repos will not save much room (since the files are likely different).  The Git Submodule command is useful for tracking the sub commits, so you can record and return to known sub commits using super git commands.  Consider also the 'subtree' command.

Comment: I took a look. Basically there is no way to merge the 2 projects into 1 big project leaving the 2 projects as independent projects so that they can be downloaded and dealt with easily while keeping them separated so that one does not see the other and vice versa while at the same time they are seen as 1 repo by GitHub ... ?